Kafka stops polling messages randomly and start polling again
I have some kafka topics with 1 partition and I am polling messages from the topic in every 2 secs,
it randomly poll zero messages for 10-15 mins and then again polled messages.
I have checked messages are there in kafka
I am expecting that if there are messages in topic it should poll
